# Question about IIS logging and time degradation

Tags: iis, logging, load-balancing

For years I always use IIS Looging always active on my sites. I currently use Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2012. The official information I follow is this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/http/iis-logging

**I have looked for official information from Microsoft asking if it is recommended to always use this feature active or it is better to enable it only when you want to trace a problem.**

- Do you know if there is any official information?
- Is there any study that says how much is the degradation of the
  response times or general speed of the site to be active?
- If I use an architecture with a Load Balancer F5 or A10 or Apache
  that connect to my nodes, is it recommended to use Logging in the
  Load Balancer always if it is deactivated in the nodes?

thanks!

Comment: The default logging is of right balance between performance and informative, so most IIS users leave it untouched. Features with performance impact are FRT and others. Therefore, I never see an official study on what you are looking for, but you can run your own metrics.

Answer (score 1):

IIS logging is processed on separate threads from the gateway services and app pools. Which means that it will not degrade performance.

Don't just take my word for it.  If you want to confirm this, you can use a capacity testing tool (not recommended on your prod server, of course). Test your capacity with logging turned-on and logging turned-off. You will see that they are comparable.